# Updating exist data using implode in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 'users' table where it has column groupID(foreign key) for table 'groups'. All user can have many groups but as for now I can only insert one group for each user. What I want to achieve is whenever user want to create new groups next time, the groupID column will have data like this [1,2]. Sorry for my bad english.

This is my code

```
public function addgroup(Request $req)
{
    $data = new Group;

    $data->groupName = $req->groupName;
    $data->groupDesc = $req->groupDesc;
    $data->userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $data->save();

    
    $g=User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $g->groupID =implode(',', (array)$data->id);
   
    $g->save();

    return redirect('redirect');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong in designing database, if users can have many group and each group can have many user, then you should create many-to-many relationship, not by storing group id in users table in array format.

this is what you should do instead.

1. create user table
2. create group table
3. create user_group table as pivot table storing user_id and group_id

then you will store the group relation in that pivot table (user_group)

read this documentation for your reference
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: hi thank you for the reply, can i ask ? this is what i found after read the reference that you give. $user = User::find(2); what is the 2 represent?

Comment: it's your primary key in user table

Comment: So how to display all the user with their groups?

Comment: if you set the relationship correctly, you can simply use this
$users = Users::with('group')->all();

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong!

You must have a users table

And a table groups

And a table: ‌

user_group

Including :

user_id,group_id

$user = User::find(1);

$group = new Group;
$group->name = "group 1";

$post = $user->group()->save($comment);